This Program gives an unexpected result when trying to push max number of items in the stack
Take a look at the code given below :-
This Code is Written to Implement Stack Using Arrays .
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Stack{
private:
    int* arr;
    int top;
    int size;

public:
    Stack(int s){ // Parameterized
        this->size = s;
        arr = new int[s];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            arr[i] = 0;
        }
        top = -1;
    }

    ~Stack( ){ // Destructor
        delete[ ]arr;
        arr = NULL;
    }

    void push(int num);
    void pop( );
    void display( );
};

void Stack::push(int num){
    if (top == size - 1){
        cout << "Stack Overflow !" << endl;
    }
    else{
        top++;
        arr[top] = num;
    }
}

void Stack::pop( ){
    if (top == -1){
        cout << "Stack is Already Empty ." << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Last Element Removed from Stack " << endl;
        arr[top] = 0;
        top--;
    }
}

void Stack::display( ){
    if (top == size - 1){
        cout << "Stack Underflow !" << endl;
        cout << "No Element Present in Stack" << endl;
    }
    else{
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            cout << arr[i] << "  ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}


int main( ){
    int choice = 0;
    int size , value , number;

    cout << "Program for Implementation of Stack using Arrays : \n" << endl;
    cout << "Enter Size of Stack : ";
    cin >> size;

    Stack s1(size);

    do{
        cout << endl;
        cout << "1. Push : Add Element at Last in Stack " << endl;
        cout << "2. Pop : Remove Last Element from Stack " << endl;
        cout << "3. Display all Element from Stack " << endl;
        cout << "4. Exit Program " << endl << endl;

        cout << "Enter Your Choice : ";
        cin >> choice;
        cout << endl;

        switch (choice){
            case 1: {
                cout << "Enter Number of Elements to Push : ";
                cin >> number;
                cout << "Enter " << number << " Element to Add in your Stack : ";
                for (int i = 0; i < number; i++){
                    cin >> value;
                    s1.push(value);
                }
                break;
            }

            case 2: {
                cout << "Enter Number of Elements to Pop : ";
                cin >> number;
                for (int i = 0; i < number; i++){
                    s1.pop( );
                }
                break;
            }

            case 3: {
                cout << "Displaying all Element from Stack : " << endl;
                s1.display( );
                break;
            }

            case 4:{
                cout << "Exiting Program ." << endl;
                break;
            }

            default: {
                cout << "Invalid Choice !" << endl;
            }
        }
    } while (choice != 4);

    return 0;
}

In the Above Code , When trying to add same amount of element as size of array then an Unexpected Output Comes.
Actual Unexpected Output
Help me in Solving this Problem.
I Think this is Happening because i have done something wrong in void Stack::display() function.

Note that C++ has the concept of Undefined behavior which means "anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But never rely on the output of a program that has UB. The program may just crash." So you've to make sure that you don't access any memory(say by dereferecing a dangling pointer etc) that not valid/legal anymore.

To make it easier to debug don't use user input. Set a known size for the stack, test one single and specific thing of the code in isolation. Also remember to build with extra warnings enabled and treated as errors, and witha sanitizer (if supported by your compiler). Then use a debugger to catch possible crashes or similar problems, or step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values.

if (top == size - 1) /* stack is empty */ That's incorrect. You represent empty stack as top == -1 (as is obvious from implementation of pop()). top == size - 1 represents a full stack (as seen in the implementation of push()), which shouldn't be a special case for display()

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) You have display() always print size elements - the capacity of the stack - even when the actual number of elements (the number of push calls minus pop calls) is less. Did you mean to print the trailing zeros representing empty slots?

Minor point: there's no need for arr = NULL; in the destructor. The object is being destroyed, and its members won't exist after the constructor returns.

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

Another side note:  This simple program has issues: int main() { Stack s(10); Stack s2 = s; } -- I leave it to you to figure out why your program has a double-free error.

You are facing this issue because you are made a mistake in the condition of the display function. In short you are using the wrong condition to check if the stack is empty or not.
You need to make few changes as shown below:

    void Stack::display() {
        if (top == -1) { 
            cout << "Stack Underflow!" << endl;
            cout << "No Element Present in Stack" << endl;
        } else {
            for (int i = top; i >= 0; i--) { 
                cout << arr[i] << "  ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }


This condition will check that if the stack if full or not and the loop for (int i = top; i >= 0; i--) will iterates only till the current top inorder to display the elements in the stack.
I hope your issue will be resolved after these changes.

Actually a stack should be displayed from the top element to the bottom.:) Last input first output (LIFO).

@VladfromMoscow Yes you are correct and based on this I have edited the response now you can have a check once again of the code.

@43H1BOI if you are completely satisfied with this answer then kindly accept (click on the tick button at top beside my answer) this answer as it will motivate me.
